# PHP Warning:  array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback...

Tags: php

Есть вот такой кусок PHP кода:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    if(!isset($_POST['ft'])){
    $_POST = @array_map(array($database->connection, 'real_escape_string'), $_POST);
    $_POST = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_POST);
    }
}

$rsargs=$_GET['rsargs'];
$_GET = array_map(array($database->connection, 'real_escape_string'), $_GET);
$_GET = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_GET);

$_GET['rsargs']=$rsargs;
$_COOKIE = array_map(array($database->connection, 'real_escape_string'), $_COOKIE);
$_COOKIE = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $_COOKIE);
```

Везде, где в функцию `array_map()` вложена функция `array()` происходит ошибка

**PHP Warning:  array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object**

Как мне убрать эту ошибку? Или достаточно в начале поставить @?

Comment: Есть такое подозрение, что ошибка именно в подключении к БД (<code>$database->connection</code>). Как думаете?

Comment: Врядли, читайте мой ответ ниже, нашел решение похожей проблемы на буржуйском форуме, переписал под ваш случай. Оригинал http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625737/mysql-real-escape-string-and-array-map-returns-blank-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сигнатура функции array_map такова, что первый параметр это callback функция, применяемая к к каждому переданному для обработки массиву. Сообщение об ошибке как раз говорит вам о том, что первый переданный вами параметр не является валидным, а именно callback функцией. Плодить @ не лучшая практика.

Comment: Есть такое подозрение, что ошибка именно в подключении к БД ($database->connection). Как думаете?

Answer (score 2):

Ну @ всего лишь отключает уведомление об ошибке, но ошибка никуда не денется. Первым параметром array_map должна быть ф-я, а вы передаете ей массив... Попробуйте так:

```
array_walk($_GET, function(&$string) use ($database->connection) { 
$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($database->connection, $string);
});
```

Можно проще обработать:

```
foreach($_GET as $value)
    $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($database->connection, $value);
```

Comment: ТС в начале пути, зачем вы мучаете его замыканиями ?)))

Comment: Ну судя по его сайту, ему нужна больше помощь в решении проблем, чем собственно обучение :) Ну и я бы сам до такого способы и не додумался, просто stackoverflow.com помогает :) Я бы на его месте тупо перебрал бы этот массив с помощью foreach

Comment: В профайле ТС черным по белому "Хочу учиться" )